# How to create alter script from two mysqldump files

Tags: mysql, database, database-schema

I'm trying to figure out how to implement migration between two databases. My plan is

1. Create mysqldump --no-data of source DB
2. Create mysqldump --no-data of target DB
3. Create alterscript based on 2 created mysqldump files
4. Run alter script on target DB to migrate new changes

However I haven't found a way to compare 2 mysqldumps and create alter script from that. Is there any tools for that?

-kari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this tool does what I need. http://search.cpan.org/dist/MySQL-Diff/bin/mysqldiff

I can compare Databases and mysqldumps and it creates alter script from differences.

Example:

```
mysqldump -uroot --no-data db1 > db1.sql
mysqldump -uroot --no-data db2 > db2.sql
mysqldiff --user=root db1.sql db2.sql
```

Comment: is there any other implementation of this tool.. Like in Java or in Go ?